# SQL: Use Lag/Lead result twice in the select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation using SQL Server where I need to use the same result of a Lag/Lead operation inside the select. There is a performance problem using the same lag/lead operation in the select? 
The select run through 10 million rows.
The partitionby/orderby of the lag/lead operation respect a compound index.

If the problem exists, so what I can do to avoid this problem?

Example of my lag/lead usage:

```
select *,
datediff( COLUMN1, LAG(SECOND, COLUMN2.......) ) AS DATE1,
datediff( COLUMN3, LAG(SECOND, COLUMN2.......) ) AS DATE2,
from mytable
```

.....

The lag operation is exactly equal. Only the first datediff param changed. I already tried to call the result of the lag 'as lagresult' and call him with @ in the datediff. Not work.

Best regards,
Luis

Comment: Show table schema and execution plans.

Comment: There should not be a noticeable performance impact.

Comment: Server is smart enough for to re-use already calculated expression value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be a noticeable performance impact.  But, if you want to express the lag only once, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       datediff( COLUMN1, prev_column_2) AS DATE1,
       datediff( COLUMN3, prev_column_2 ) AS DATE2,
from (select t.*,
             LAG(COLUMN2) OVER ( . . . ) as prev_column2
      from mytable t
     ) t
```

By moving the expression to the `FROM` clause, SQL Server is much more likely to evaluate it only once.